Flutter FlutterContacts.getContacts get phone number reversed
contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(       withProperties: true, withPhoto: true); Contact contact = await FlutterContacts.getContact(contacts.first.id);

that code must return phone number, and it does exactly what I want, except for some numbers that are returned in revers order
